# Facebook comments feature puts comments on all postings .

Tags: facebook

I am working on the site which is a classified ads website . I  have integrated the face book comment feature , but when someone comment on one job , then the comments are displayed on all job positing . How can I fix this? I have tried Google I did not get anything to fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify a different value for the data-href parameter. For example:

```
data-href="http://yourdomain.com/?jobid=2"
```

Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

Comment: but remember we post new jobs every day

Comment: the important thing is: different href parameter, different comments ;) - just use the permalink for the job.

Comment: thanks but will that make the new jobs get there targeted comments ?

Comment: well...that´s kind of in my answer ;)